# Cage graphs and even cycles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

Let $G$ be a $(\nu,g)$-[cage graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CageGraph.html) of degree $\nu$ with girth $g$ and $n=n(\nu,g)$ vertices.
Based on the known examples, I am wondering if the following can be proved/disproved:

> - ***Is it true that a cage graph with even girth has cycles of all even lengths between $g$ and $n$?*** If not, what can be said about "missing" cycle lengths?
> - Knowing that the Petersen graph is so often good for an exception or counterexample: ***is the Petersen graph the only non hamiltonian cage graph?***